# how to find order of convergence from sequence.

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

We have $3$ sequences of $\sin\left(\frac1{n}\right), \sin\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)$ and $\sin^2\left(\frac1{n}\right)$. How to find the order of convergence if we know that $\sin x≤x$ for $x≥0$ so $\sin\left(\frac1{n}\right)≤\frac1{n}$.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? The main facts are already written down, you only need to apply them. If you want a stronger result use that $\sin(x)=x(1+O(x^2))$ to show that the convergence is not faster than what you get from the given bound.

Comment: With the given input, you can't.

Comment: i can't change it into equation using big oh. Any explanation?